# Can't commit to github remote via ssh after installing zsh

Tags: git, github, ssh, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had SSH key paired with my Win10 machine and Github account, and it's was working on Bash, but today I installed ZSH (oh-my-zsh) via WSL, and now when I'm trying to push I see the next error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In **ZSH**:

```sh
ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

In **Bash**:

```sh
$ ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
Hi UserName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Are you using `bash` via WSL as well, or Git Bash?

Comment: Please run ssh with the "-v" option to print debugging info, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed ZSH on Ubuntu (WSL2) in order to follow your steps. In my case, I could push to the remote via ZSH shell.
The problem seems to be in your SSH key **inside WSL**.
Follow the step to generate another key to pair **inside** your WSL.

This is so because your first SSH key from Windows is located in one place and the SSH key that you need now need to be placed inside WSL.

Answer (score 1):

As in [`ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh` issue 7891](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/7891), check the content of your `~/.zshrc`, and make sure there is no alias for `ssh`.

An `ssh -Tv` will, as commented, shows you exactly what files are considered by the ssh command in your zsh session.

Comment: Would `git push` use `ssh` alias or a binary?

Comment: @phd Only if there is a config like `git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/`

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue

successfully authenticated with the bash terminal.

but when trying with zsh It gave me either
**Permission denied** or trying with the other git account
Problem: in zsh `ssh-add` was not working.
you have to add `ssh-agent` plugin in your ~/.zshrc file

`plugins=( git ssh-agent)`